# Print in text instead of binary format in cat implementation

Tags: c, file, stdout, cat

The implementation of the `cat` program is printing in binary format on the Ubuntu terminal. I am using the `stdout` macro (object of type `FILE*`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    void add(FILE*, FILE*);
    if (argc==1)
        add(stdin,stdout);
    else
        while(--argc>0)
        {
            if ((fp=fopen(*++argv,"r"))==NULL)
            {
                printf("cat:can't open %s\n",*argv);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                add(fp,stdout);    // printing all the file content on the screen.
                fclose(fp);
            }
            return(0);
        }
}

void add(FILE*p,FILE*q)
{
    int c;
    while((c=fgetc(p))!=EOF)
    {
        fputc(c,q);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I print in text format instead of binary format?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary format" and "text format"?

Comment: what kind of file you're printing, is it a plain text ?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: `while(--argv>0)` should be `while(--argc>0)`. Why don't you use the simple loop `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) process(argv[i])`?

Comment: @axiac i mean output is in machine readable language i am looking in text format (human readable language)

Comment: @MOehm bcoz time complicity will be  more with your loop you memtioned above

Comment: `while(--argv>0)` doesn't make any sense. `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers i.e. an address in memory, why do you compare it with `0`? @MOehm is right and the code they suggests is easier to read and understand. And no, you didn't optimize anything by writing the code that way. The time complexity is the same and it is given by the big data transfer you do in function `add()`.

Comment: @user4950013 why is time complexity relevant when looping a few program arguments?

Comment: @axiac i think cat implementation is done in the same way isn't it?

Comment: You should not have fixed your typo error in your posted code. The question does not make sense anymore: `argv>0` fixed with `argc>0`. Your loop-wories are nonsense.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in how you loop over the arguments. Stripping your code of the actual file processing and replacing it with a print statement (and also nicely indenting it), we get:

```
if (argc == 1)
    printf("stdin\n");
else
    while (--argv > 0) {
        printf("'%s'\n", *++argv);
    }
```

You have mistyped `argc` for `argv` in your code. That means you decrement the pointer to the first argument and then increment it again before processing the file. Effectively, you end up processing `argv[0]` over and over. That file is the program itself, which is binary and contains many non-printable characters.

You should chzange the loop to

```
    while (--argc > 0) {
        printf("'%s'\n", *++argv);
    }
```

or use a pedestrian `for` loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("'%s'\n", argv[i]);
    }
```

Comment: sorry to say what all i am trying to do is if there are command-line arguments,they are interpreted as filenames and processed in order and if there are no arguments ,the standard input is processed  and ya i do agree there was typo mistake of argv instead of argc. now mine code is working good by removing correcting typo miss . for loop is more costly here anyway even in this case it is good to use ++i instead ++i check **http://www.spatial.com/blog/3d-software-development-kits/pre-increment-vs-post-increment-part1** ++i is shorter than i++

Comment: (1) Please organise both your code and your comments in a way that they are readable. (2) Worry about correct, stable and maintainable code before looking into performance.

Comment: (3) The article you linked is about C++, where the pre and post increments may be overloaded operators of classes. In that case, you should prefer the prefix notation, because the postfix notation must make a copy of the object. This question is about C, where the increment can apply only to arithmetic and pointer types. The compiler notices that the expression `i++` is in void context and creates the same code as for `++i`. (The same goes for basic types in C++, which is mentioned in the article.)

Comment: ok you said " Worry about correct, stable and maintainable code before looking into performance" Can you let me know what is not correct (except typo which i have fixed) or not stable.I am so afraid all the people are just put down vote without going through the code.

Comment: If the code had been correct, you wouldn't have posted it here. If it had been maintainable (i.e. properly laid out and using common idioms), you would have found the typo. You fear that you are worried that people downvote without reading the code, yet you make bold statements about time complexity, which apparently you don't quite understand, and link to articles that you haven't read completely. I haven't downvoted your question, but I'd say that many people here are put off by the initial formatting of your code and your behaviour in the comments.

Comment: Also, please don't just fix the code in the question, unless there are still other errors in the program. If the code runs now (it does, doesn't it?), the question doesn't make sense any longer.

Comment: The only trouble i can see in my code is that if one of the files can't be accessed for some reason ,the diagnostic is printed at the end of the concatenated output,and this situation can be handle using second output stream stderr rest all is good if you can prove still a code has kind of errors or buys i will surely accept you answer between to all the vote downer please let newcomers to find their way!!!

Comment: i++ makes a copy, increases i, and returns the copy (old value).
 ++i increases i, and returns i.This is the reason i feel ++i is faster.

Comment: Anyway you was the first to catch typo so will go with your answer,thank you

Answer (score 1):

program has no any error only typo mistake argv instead argc rest all  is good even than above suggested answer